# JSR 354 Money in Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, currency, java-money, jsr354

I need to do Money calculations in my application that is java 8. Since the operations i need to do are basic operations, i am considering creating my own money class. <strike>But looking at the long term i see Java9 has its own Money implementation which we might want to migrate to when we move our application to java 9.</strike>

Is there anyway i can use JSR 354 implementation for money in Java 8? if yes, would that be the recommended way right now to do Money in Java 8 right now?
https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr354/index.html

EDIT: I was wrong, JSR 354 is not in Java 9. But my question still stands on how to use Money in Java 8 and is this the recommended way to deal with Money in jAva.

Comment: The JSR-354 money API is not in Java 9. The page you link to has a link to the reference implementation which can be used on Java 8.

Answer (score 4):

Basically, there is two way to use it:

1. Using the dependency described [there](https://dzone.com/articles/looking-java-9-money-and)

in your *pom.xml*

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.javamoney</groupId>
  <artifactId>moneta</artifactId>
  <version>0.9</version>
</dependency>
```

2. The second way from [the repository](https://github.com/JavaMoney/jsr354-api). Here is dependency:

in your *pom.xml*

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.money</groupId>
    <artifactId>money-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```